# Sort array keys where key matches inner array's value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of arrays where outer array's key matches inner array's value 'id_rel'.

Example array:

```
array = (
  [5] => array (
      ['content'] => 'some text',
      [id_rel] => 88
  ),
  [49] => array (
      ['content'] => 'some text',
      [id_rel] => NULL
  ),
  [88] => array (
      ['content'] => 'some text',
      [id_rel] => 5
  ),
  [3] => array (
      ['content'] => 'some text',
      [id_rel] => NULL
  )
)
```

In this example, item [5] has 'id_rel' of '88', which refers to item [88] in the array. I would like move those two items next to each other.

This is how it should look like after sorting (note, keys should remain unchanged):

```
array = (
  [5] => array (
      ['content'] => 'some text',
      [id_rel] => 88
  ),
  [88] => array (
      ['content'] => 'some text',
      [id_rel] => 5
  ),
  [49] => array (
      ['content'] => 'some text',
      [id_rel] => NULL
  ),
  [3] => array (
      ['content'] => 'some text',
      [id_rel] => NULL
  )
)
```

What would be the best way to achieve sorting like this?

Comment: since the array `id` index is the key of the parent array you caould use key sort `ksort`

Comment: `ksort($array); for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) { sort($array[$i]); }` EDIT: nevermind the for loop I thought you wanted to sort the inner arrays as well. `ksort`: http://nl3.php.net/ksort

Comment: What are you sorting on? The key of the array?

Comment: I am sorting keys that match 'id_rel' from inner arrays.

Comment: @Tomas The sort criteria is unclear could you elaborate on your example?

Comment: What you ask for is not (easily) possible, in your example the stuff that needs to be sorted is neatly next to each other, what if the `5` was between the `88` and `49`? (I am myself not looking for an answer to that question, good luck with it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
$newArray = array();
ksort($array);
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    // Add it to the new array
    $newArray[$key] = $val;
    // Remove it
    unset($array[$key]);

    // If no id_rel, move on
    if (empty($val['id_rel'])) {
        continue;
    }

    // Get id_rel's
    foreach ($array as $subKey => $subVal) {
        if ($subKey == $val['id_rel']) {
            $newArray[$subKey] = $subVal;
            unset($array[$subKey]);
        }
    }
}
unset($array, $subKey, $subVal, $key, $val);
var_dump($newArray);
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/SVRq5g

Answer (score 0):

Fairly ugly way of doing it but you can create a custom sort:

```
$arr = array(
  5 => array (
      'id' => 5,
      'content' => 'some text',
      'id_rel' => 88
  ),
  49 => array (
        'id' => 49,
      'content'=> 'some text',
      'id_rel' => NULL
  ),
  88 => array (
        'id' => 88,
      'content' => 'some text',
      'id_rel' => 5
  ),
  3 => array (
        'id' => 3,
      'content' => 'some text',
      'id_rel' => NULL
  )
);
uasort($arr,function($a, $b){
    if(empty($a['id_rel']) && !empty($b['id_rel'])){
        return 1;
    }elseif(empty($b['id_rel']) && !empty($a['id_rel'])){
        return -1;
    }
    if($a['id_rel'] == $b['id'] || $a['id'] == $b['id_rel']){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return $b['id']-$a['id'];
    }
});
print_r($arr);
```

Note that this array has an `'id'` field otherwise `uasort` doesn't have access to the `id`.